# Thymeleaf th:text fill from url

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I wan't fill the text attribute from url :

```
<span th:text="@{/admin/user/getUserName}"></span>
```

RestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/getUserName")
public String getUserName(){

    return "Hello From Controller";
}
```

I expect attribute text set by "Hello From Controller" but the value that set is "/admin/user/getUserName". could somebody help me?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Patrick i edit my question.

Comment: This isn't how Thymeleaf templates work. You have to return the name of the template in the MVC Controller, and pass the data in a Model. The HTML is created by the Thymeleaf templating engine, based on the template (HTML file) and the data you pass from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this goal like this way (using jquery):
In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/user/getUserName")
@ResponseBody
public String getUserName(){
    return "Hello From Controller";
}
```

In view:

```
<span id="tt"></span>

<script>
    $(function () {
       $("#tt").load("/admin/user/getUserName");
    });
</script>
```